# Cannot read property 'castForQuery' of undefined at castArrayFilters in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using **arrayFilters** as option in **findOneAndUpdate** (in **mongoose**) to **update** value of *name* and *isRecursive* fields in TimetableModel.
The fields are updating **successfully** in **MongoDb** but also I am getting the **exception**, which is being added at the end of this query.

What am I supposed to do to eliminate this exception?

Following are the details of my work:

> **Versions:** "mongodb": "^3.1.13",
>       "mongoose": "^5.4.9",

this is the Schema:

```
const timetableSchema = new Schema({
individualId: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    required: true
},
date: {
    type: Number,
    required: false
},
time: []});
```

this is the logic:

```
TimetableModel.findOneAndUpdate({
        individualId: req.query.individualId,
        date: req.query.date,
    }, {
        'time.$[i].name': req.query.name,
        'time.$[i].isRecursive': req.query.isRecursive,
    }, {
        arrayFilters: [{
            'i.timeSlot': req.query.timeSlot
        }],
    }, function (err, result) {
        if (result) {
            resolve(result);
        } else if (err) {
            reject(err);
        }
    }).catch((err) => {
        reject(err);
    })
```

and this is the exception

> "TypeError: Cannot read property 'castForQuery' of undefined
>      at castArrayFilters (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/ParentsPlus/ParentsPlusRepo/parents-plus-back-end/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/update/castArrayFilters.js:59:37)
>      at _castArrayFilters (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/ParentsPlus/ParentsPlusRepo/parents-plus-back-end/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:1739:5)
>      at model.Query.Query._findAndModify (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/ParentsPlus/ParentsPlusRepo/parents-plus-back-end/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:3205:3)
>      at model.Query. (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/ParentsPlus/ParentsPlusRepo/parents-plus-back-end/node_modules/mongoose/lib/query.js:2830:8)
>      at model.Query._wrappedThunk [as _findOneAndUpdate] (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/ParentsPlus/ParentsPlusRepo/parents-plus-back-end/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/query/wrapThunk.js:16:8)
>      at process.nextTick (/Users/user/Desktop/Projects/ParentsPlus/ParentsPlusRepo/parents-plus-back-end/node_modules/kareem/index.js:369:33)
>      at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:132:7)
>      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:181:9)"

Answer (score -1):

I think there is a bug since version `5.4.4` or **maybe another previous version**. It was reported [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/7603). For the moment I solved it by downloading the mongoose version to `5.3.15`.

Comment: I am already using updated mongoose version as you can see above in my question

Comment: @AsadUllah i say **since**, and I tell you that you could solve it by going down to version `5.3.15` if you do not have any inconveniences.